# jQuery slideToggle on a table with thead and tbody elements. No animation.

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have a table with a thead and tbody sections. I have applied a slideToggle on this successfully, but the animation is broken.

When a user clicks on the thead, I want the contents of the tbody to slide up. Currently what happens is the section simply disappears, without any animation.

Here is the table

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">TABLE HEADING</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first" colspan="1">Cell Contents</td>
      <td colspan="1">Cell Contents</td>
      <td colspan="1">Cell Contents</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the jQuery I am using:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $("thead").click(function () {
               $(this).next("tbody").slideToggle("slow");
            }
         )
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: These bugs happen most probably because of height settings in css.

Comment: So, perhaps I should set a height for it through jQuery when the click is triggered?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It disappears because `<tbody>` normally will get no shorter than the tallest `td`, no matter what you set its height to with CSS.

This is why the natural-height `tbody` just seems to disappear, while the one with artificial extra-height appears to run until the `tr` reached its natural height.

You can kludge around this with `tbody {display:block;}`.  [See the kludge at jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/K7yxC/5/)

**But**, [notice the effect that has when a table height is set.](http://jsfiddle.net/K7yxC/4/)

Probably, the best way is to wrap the whole table in a div and `slideToggle` that, like so:

```
<table class="AbbyNormal">
    <thead><tr><td colspan="3">TABLE HEADING</td></tr></thead>
</table>
<div class="tableWrap">
    <table class="AbbyNormal">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="first" colspan="1">Cell Contents</td>
            <td colspan="1">Cell Contents</td>
            <td colspan="1">Cell Contents</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Just be sure and fix the table widths the same.

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/K7yxC/6/)

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem. I ended up wrapping it in a div and using a slideToggle on the div itself.

Comment: How does this solution only have so few upvotes??? Thanks much, @Brock Adams! Ran into the same problem this morning and your solution was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set an height to the tbody to make it work, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/AsDvb/

css:

```
tbody{

    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I've done that, but now what seems to happen is the animation runs until the tr are at the minimum height then they just disappear.