# Collapse/Expand Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a little jquery help to collapse/expand a table that I have on my site. I'd also like the table to start expanded.

Here is an example of a table I have:

```
<table class="table">
  <caption>
  <div class="video-header">Header</div>
  </caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="video-row">
      <td class="field-title"> Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="video-row">
      <td class="field-title"> More Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like it that when you click on the "Header" that it collapses the entire table, not just the row.

I've found the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/), but can't seem to translate it to my case.

Comment: This table is being generated by the Drupal CMS. Not much I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a [click handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for the caption element

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('table > caption').click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pxbtt/)

Comment: Arun, would it be possible to have a "+/-" symbol to show when it is collapsed or expanded?

Comment: Thanks Arun! One more question, is there anyway to make the collapse and expand have a sliding transition rather then just showing and disappearing?

Comment: @Dan it looks a little difficult with current markup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882522/jquery-slidetoggle-on-a-table-with-thead-and-tbody-elements-no-animation

Answer (score 0):

because your table is generated dynamically, you should define a parent node in which the table is located. this parent node should always exist in the page and should **NOT** be generated dynamically.

```
  <div id="table-container">
    <table class="table">
      <caption>
      <div class="video-header">Header</div>
      </caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="video-row">
          <td class="field-title"> Content </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="video-row">
          <td class="field-title"> More Content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

then bind `click` event on that parent node.

```
$("#table-container caption").on("click", function(){
  $("#table-container table").css("display", "none");
});
```