# transition animate to slide up and down the table-body

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css-transitions

I'd like to have a slide up and slide down effect for my table body, when I click on my table header. So far I managed to display and hide the table body onclick, but not with a slide down/up transition! The transition for the table body with the opacity worked fine.

Is it possible to slide the body up and down, since I can't really set the height of my body to 0 and therefore have no real height transition? I can just display it as none and then as block (etc.), but then I have no height transition.

So far I am working with angularjs (ng-show/hide). If there is an angular-animation way, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Brocks answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882522/jquery-slidetoggle-on-a-table-with-thead-and-tbody-elements-no-animation

Comment: Nice, thanks. Unfortunately I didn't find it during my research.